# Set Showheader to false using javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have below code to open visualforce page from lightning component. 
But if i open vf page from lightning showHeader should set it as false. Is it possible to achieve this?

```
window.open('/apex/OpenVFPage');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, but you could use a page parameter:

```
<apex:page showHeader="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.showHeader != 'false'}">
```

Which you can then set via a URL parameter:

```
window.open('/apex/OpenVFPage?showHeader=false');
```

Comment: This seems to be not working. window.open('/apex/OpenVFPage?showHeader=false');

Comment: i need to use only window.open code but somehow i need to make showHeader=false

Comment: @ChaithraKN You need to allow the page to accept the parameter. You'll need to modify your page as I demonstrated. If you can't, you might want to look in to using `isdtp=mn`, but this will have other side effects as well.

Comment: I updated page to have showHeader="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.showHeader != 'false'}" . It started working. Thanks for your help. If i use isdtp=mn what may be the side effects?

Comment: @ChaithraKN It also changes the style sheets slightly. You can choose whichever method you prefer.

Comment: Okey, Can we use isdtp=mn for managed package VF pages also?

Comment: @ChaithraKN yes, the isdtp parameter works on all Visualforce pages. I suggest googling it to see what the valid values are; they have different effects on styling.